# Can't pass parameters to bash script from zsh

Tags: bash, parameter-passing

My bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

 main(){
  name=${1:-you}
  echo "One for $name, one for me."
}

 main "@a"
```

I'm trying to pass the parameters from zsh terminal like this

```
bash tw_fer.sh Adem
```

It always returns @a nothing else. How can I print the argument that I've passed?

Comment: There is no `zsh` involved in your code. You just pass to `main` the string `@a`, and this is output in the `echo` statement. What effect would you have expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `"@a"` by `"$1"` for only first parameter or `"${@}"` for all parameters